# string formatting in a cocoa tutorial

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string

I am doing a Cocoa tutorial where I need to count the characters in a field, then output something like 'the_string_i_am_count' has 21 characters.

I have managed to get the string, count it, and output the count but I have no idea how to output the count along with the string and the other info.

How would I do this?

```
-(IBAction)countCharacters:(id)sender
{
    //i had to connect this to the class also to make it get the value.
    //NSString *string = [inputField stringValue];

    //get the number of chars
    NSUInteger length = [[inputField stringValue] length];

    [outputField setIntValue:length]; //string];
    //[outputField setStringValue: @"'s' has %d characters.", string, length];
}
```

Semi working code:

```
-(IBAction)countCharacters:(id)sender
{
    //i had to connect this to the class also to make it get the value.
    NSString *string = [inputField stringValue];

    //get the number of chars
    NSUInteger length = [[inputField stringValue] length];

    [outputField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%s' has %d characters.", string, length]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[outputField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has %@ characters.", string, length]];
```

Comment: Could you update your original post with the updated code that you are using?  This way I could help you further.

Comment: There you go. `string` is being set because if I do something like `string = @"test";` and output it then it works fine. Just not in the `stringWithFormat`

Comment: Use my code that I used above.  NSString isn't an %s, it's a %@ because it is a Obj-C object.

Comment: Yea it crashes if I use `%@` for the int but `%@` works for the `string` thanks!